# Garage Ceiling corner Brace

Tags: drywall, garage, truss

I have these braces nailed into the wall plates i believe they keep the garage from racking/ twisting and are code here in california for earthquake from what i’ve read. Is there a different way that i can support the corners so that i can hang drywall? it’s an attached garage so only the 2 front corners have these braces [image]

Comment: Nothing there preventing you from hanging drywall. Might require *a bit more work* than whatever you envision with these gone, but getting these gone will probably require consulting a seismic/structural engineer, then implementing whatever they come up with as an alternative, and that will cost a good bit; so doing the bit more work to hang drywall as is, is probably the more fiscally sensible approach.

Comment: @Ecnerwal so you mean just butting up the drywall to the side of 2x4 ?

Comment: One of many options. You could drywall the face and edges of the 2x4 and run the rest at joist height, if you want complete gypsum coverage. You could fur down the triangles from the brace edges to the corners lower than the rest, running at two heights,  etc.

Comment: i didn’t think of that makes things a lot easier and cheaper . thank you

Comment: If you feel like making a design statement, sand and stain the 2x4s and just butt the drywall up to them.  Easy.

Comment: thats probably what im going to end up doing or just matching the ceiling paint. thanks

Answer (score 2):

One possible different way than taking out the angled pieces:

Fur down the rest of the rafters with appropriate-width wood rips to the bottom of the angled pieces. Then drywall the ceiling.